# Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Suppose that $f\colon (a, b)\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and there exists a point $p\in (a, b)$ such that $f'$ exists and is bounded on $(a, b)\setminus \{p\}$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$

I am a little confused about the question. Whether $f'(p)$ exists or not in the description : "$f'$ exists and is bounded on $(a, b)\setminus \{p\}$". If $f'(p)$ exists, then I have proved it. But if $f'(p)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,p)$ and $(p,b)$. That doesn't require $f'(p)$ to exist.

Comment: An example of a uniformly continuous function $f$ on $(-1,1)$ but with no derivative on $0$ is for instance $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much.